# Digest authentication generate 'token'

Tags: php, cakephp, digest, digest-authentication

I am currently using Digest authentication. While reading about it, I found "If the check is successful, the domain "controller notifies the server that the client is authentic. A Digest Authentication session key is also returned to the originating server. If the check is not successful, the originating server sends the client an error message. After a successful authentication, the originating server allows the client to access the resource indicated by the URI."

However, I do not want the user to enter `username` and `password` every time, is it possible to generate `key` or `token` by code and give it to the user for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic and Digest authentications are based on the browser session.

They will be logged in until they close out their browser.  Meaning, they won't have to log in each time they visit a different page.

The same goes for the authentication, if you're looking for something other than what you have for Basic and Digest, then you'll need to use a different authentication schema.

CakePHP has form authentication built in, and that may be the route you wish to go.